# How to properly implement bagging on decision tree with for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree, ensemble-learning

I am trying to implement bagging and voting using a decision tree and for loop. I am using sklearn resample. However, I get `Number of labels=97 does not match number of samples=77` and I can kind of see why but I'm not sure how to fix it.

There are 150 samples in the dataset. 
There are 150 labels
so 150 * 0.35 = 97
and 97 * 0.8 = 77.
 X is the feature matrix of length 150, and 
 y is the label vector of length 150

Below is my code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.utils import resample


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.35, random_state=3)

predictions = []

for i in range(1,20):
    bootstrap_size = int(0.8*len(X_train))
    bag = resample(X_train, n_samples = bootstrap_size , random_state=i , replace = True) 
    Base_DecisionTree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=3)
    Base_DecisionTree.fit(bag, y_train)
    y_predict = Base_DecisionTree.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_predict)
    predictions.append(accuracy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resample also labels and use it in `fit()`.

```
x_bag, y_bag = resample(X_train, y_train, n_samples = bootstrap_size , random_state=i , replace = True) 
tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=3)
tree.fit(x_bag, y_bag)
```

Comment: Yeah, that works. But why are all the predictions the same? `[0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831, 0.8301886792452831]`

Comment: Silly me, I had to restart kernel on jupyter. Thank you for your help.